# Divs Overlay Simple Implemantation

Tags: html, css

I've a Div (id=placeholder), which sits in a table cell, the one has three nested div's (content1, content2 and content3). I want these nested divs to have the same size as their parent (id=placeholder) and overlay each other.

What is the simplest way to achieve that? I'm looking for a cross-browser solution.

Html

```
<table><tr><td>

<div id='placeholder'>
  <div id='content1' class='overlay'>...</div>
  <div id='content2' class='overlay'>...</div>
  <div id='content3' class='overlay'>...</div>
<div>

</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css

```
.overlay { position: absolute; }
```

html

```
<div id='placeholder'>
  <div id='content1' class='overlay'>...</div>
  <div id='content2' class='overlay'>...</div>
  <div id='content3' class='overlay'>...</div>
<div>
```

And you will need to `clearfix` inside the cell to stretch table cell by the height.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/v6Jnr/

**Upd: Added cross-browser `clearfix`**

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/v6Jnr/2/

Comment: Would you want to throw a `position:relative` on the `#placeholder` to  make sure the nested divs don't break out to some other element? Or is that unnecessary in this situation?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need `position:relative` somewhere, otherwise your absolute positioning will default to the top left of your browser window.

Comment: @Samich I've slightly more complex Html than the one I've posted - by some reason content2 is shown beneath the content1 as opposed to overlaying it. Would you know what the problem is?

Comment: Try changing the z-index. And you don't need a relatively positioned parent, as long as you don't position the overlays (top, left, ...).